# Not able to update the output panels

Tags: jsf, primefaces, facelets

I am not able to update both the output panels after the ajax call of a method in the backing bean.

Code looks like below given sample code

abc.xhtml

```xml
<p:outputPanel id="criteriaPanel" rendered="#{myBean.showPanel}">
   <h:form id="loginForm">
     <ui:include src="login.xhtml" />
     <p:commandButton action="#{myBean.login}" value="Login" update="criteriaPanel successPanel" />
   </h:form>
</p:outputPanel> 

<p:outputPanel id="successPanel" rendered="#{!myBean.showPanel}">
   <h:form id="successForm">
     <ui:include src="success.xhtml" />
   </h:form>
</p:outputPanel>
```

MyBean.java

```java
public class MyBean {
  private boolean showPanel = true;

  public void login() {
    this.setShowPanel(false);
  }

  public void setShowPanel(boolean showPanel) {
    this.showPanel = showPanel;
  }

  public boolean isShowPanel() {
    return showPanel;
  }

}
```

Comment: The includes are probably causing the problem. Try putting the code for the includes right into the panel for now.  I have to check but a form tag inside the panel may also be an issue.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Just take inside both of the .xhtml file  one <h:outputText /> is there.

Comment: I don't understand your reply. Did you get rid of the includes?  If so, did it work?

Comment: yeah,I had removed both the .xhtml files.Still it is not working....

Comment: @AbaniSahoo what's the scope of your backing bean? It looks like you have a misunderstanding of how to stack container panels in the context of ajax page updates

Comment: @kolossus thanks for your reply,my backing bean is ViewScoped.